# two collection crossover and get result

Tags: java, collections

I have two collection like this:
(two collection have same size)

```
A:  [a,b,c]
B:  [d,e,f]
```

I want to get a crossover result like this:

```
[ [a,e,f],[a,b,f],[d,b,c],[d,b,f],[d,b,c],[d,e,c],[a,e,c],[a,b,c],[d,e,f]... ]
```

How can I get all posibily result, and what is max posibility in this case;

Comment: You should try something rather than expect others to fully solve the problem for you. And, in this specific case, you should describe the target result more clearly. In any case, this has to be done via nested loops. You could, for example, create a main for loop iterating through all the elements in the first array and, inside it, a secondary one to iterate through the second array. Inside this secondary loop, you can add the results to a third array in the way you want via conditions, continue/break, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 8 permutations. Suppose we substitute A with `[0,0,0]` and B with `[1,1,1]`. The result now looks like this:

```
000
100
010
110
001
101
011
111
```

Conveniently, this is the binary range of integers 0 through 7. So one way to solve this is to count to 7 (i.e. `2 ^ length - 1`), and treat each bit as a toggle between list A and list B:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1 << a.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++) {
        List<String> source = (i & 1 << j) == 0 ? a : b;
        System.out.print(source.get(j));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
abc
dbc
aec
dec
abf
dbf
aef
def
```

[**Ideone Demo**](https://ideone.com/snPWHI)